# How to use EndNote instead of FootNote on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I am looking for a way to put my footnotes at the end of the document (as "EndNote") (or at the end of a chapter), or even to hide them.

Since there is no web-viewing mode, the footnotes are shown on the bottom of each page. It's annoying since they cut the text. It would be great to be able to hide them or display them as end-notes.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

*EDIT:* thanks to paulhastings0 we can now convert footnotes to endnotes. But it's only a workaround since *we need both footnotes to endnotes*. If you also want both of them, star [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763960) (the more stars the better chance we have).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encourage you to submit your request for this capability directly to the Docs Team. The more requests they receive for a feature, the more likely they will work on it.

You should do both:

**1) star [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5566&thanks=5566&ts=1448701203) coding feature request**
*(Then go to the setting of this page (the gear on the right) and disable all notifications, or you'll be flooded by "me too!" emails).*

<s>This issue has been blocked by google.</s>  (EDIT: not anymore)

**2) Submit a Feedback**

2. Open a Google Docs document.
3. Go to Help > Docs help.
4. Click on Send feedback (at the bottom).
5. Write: *we need an EndnoteSection*
6. Press the blue Send button.

(Source: [Jo's answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/JP1ERfkypYY;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Adocuments$20feature$20request$20end$20notes))

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had the same problem and created a Google Docs Add-on that automatically converts all of your footnotes into end-notes. I've used it without any hiccups.

You can download it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/endnote-generator/nmhebcalinkmgflgcfapknjhbliebooc).